# Area of a Semi-Regular Decagon

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to calculate the area of the floor plan of an oddly shaped cabin my in-laws own.

The cabin is a semi-regular decagon with sides 10 and 20 alternating.

I recognize that if I could solve for the distance from the center to the mid-point of the sides (apothem) then this becomes pretty easy by decomposing the problem into 2 sets of 5 equal triangles.

Edit: Thanks for the help here. My previous assertion on the bounding of the area was incorrect so I have removed it.

Comment: Thinking about this more. Are there two unique apothem corresponding to each of the different side lengths or a common apothem?

Comment: Are you saying that the polygon is circumscribable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the decagon is circumscribable (i.e. there's a circle going through all its vertices)... Just find the area of a triangle with sides $a=20$, $b=10$ and angle between these two sides of $144$ degrees. Also find the third side $c$ of this triangle (e.g. by using cosine theorem). Then your decagon is simply composed of 5 such triangles plus a regular pentagon with side $c$. So finding its area presents no problems.

I can try to make a drawing too.

Comment: Your answer is obviously correct once you have made a drawing and spotted that $180^\circ - \frac{360^\circ}{10}=144^\circ$

Comment: I think it is safe to assume it is circumscribable. May need an aerial view to confirm. That is just the mental visualization I needed thanks!!!

Comment: @JJFord3 OK, good luck :)